# How can I control the output formats used by Ruby CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'd like to be able to change the date and time formats used by [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) when generating csv output. For example, instead of generating '2004-1-30' for a date, I'd like it to generate '1/30/2004'.

How can I do that?

Comment: `'1/30/2004'` Is it `day/month/year` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit More likely [month/day/year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_month-day-year). That's a commonly used format in the US.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I always confused with this...:p Common sense In world never we do have month # 30..

Comment: It's just an example. I'm asking about formatting mechanisms in general, But since 2004 can only be a year and therefore 30 can only be a month, 1 must be the day within the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example :

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

str = <<_
2004-1-30,foo
2004-11-20,bar
_

File.write('a',str)

CSV::Converters[:cdate] = lambda do |s|
  begin
  Date.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%-m/%d/%Y")
  rescue ArgumentError
    s
  end
end

CSV.foreach('a',:converters => :cdate) do |row|
  p row
end
# >> ["1/30/2004", "foo"]
# >> ["11/20/2004", "bar"]
```

Look at the documentation of [`Converters`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters).

> An Array of names from the Converters `Hash` and/or `lambdas` that handle *custom conversion*. *A single converter doesn’t have to be in an Array*. All built-in converters try to transcode fields to UTF-8 before converting. The conversion will fail if the data cannot be transcoded, leaving the field unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, Arup. I actually stared at that Converters documentation for some time and tried running some of the converters manually, but couldn't make heads or tails of it. I ended up concluding that they were input formatters, not output formatters. Anyway, now that I have some example code from you, I'll go back and try to understand it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin **Remember** *converters* applicable only during reading the `CSV` files.

Comment: Hmmm. So is there any way I can feed a regular `Date` object to `CSV.generate` and control through CSV what happens when it turns it into a string? Or do all objects get turned into strings through `.to_s` or some such as the very first step in processing?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin `CSV.generate` is *writing to a csv* file. SO *converters* wouldn't be helpful. You can put, But the `Date` object will be converted to string inside the  CSV..